# Making Theme Config Fields multilang?

Tags: shopware

I know you can make non editable config values multilang in via `src/Resources/config/config.xml` but is it also possible for fields defined in `src/Resources/theme.json`?

Comment: Yes, check out the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/theme-configuration#field-types).

Comment: Are you talking about translating the setting labels of have real translated values such as a text input which the user can fill with different strings, by language? As there is no language switcher on /admin#/sw/theme/manager/detail/ I believe the later one is not possible.

Comment: @PawełNapierała this is only taking care of the labels. But I am talking about multilang **values**

Comment: @Alex yeas I am talking about translatable values, not labels.

Comment: @owzim sorry, I didn't understand the question right. I suppose it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be possible as in the admin panel you cannot switch the language at that point.